# Key error on idxmax in df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas grouped dataframe that I created with:

```
Prof_file=prof_claims.groupby(['TC_Code', 'Primary_CPT_Description'])
grp_prof=Prof_file['Total_Case_AMT'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.count_nonzero])
```

Now I want to find the longest string in the field 'Primary_CPT_Description'.

I am using

```
grp_prof.ix[grp_prof['Primary_CPT_Description'].idxmax()]
```

I have also tried

```
print grp_prof.groupby(['Primary_CPT_Description']).idxmax()
```

However I keep getting an error: KeyError: u'no item named Primary_CPT_Description'

That does not seem to make sense as I definitely have 'Primary_CPT_Description' as a string field in the df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `grp_prof` probably looks something like this (manufactured data, but you get the idea):

```
>>> grp_prof
                                 sum  mean  count_nonzero
TC_Code Primary_CPT_Description                          
0       5                         15    15              1
1       6                         16    16              1
2       7                         17    17              1
3       8                         18    18              1
4       9                         19    19              1
```

See how `TC_Code` and `Primary_CPT_Description` are lower than `sum`, `mean`, and `count_nonzero`?  They're not columns, they're part of the index:

```
>>> grp_prof.columns
Index([u'sum', u'mean', u'count_nonzero'], dtype='object')
>>> grp_prof.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=[u'TC_Code', u'Primary_CPT_Description'])
```

I'd probably use `.reset_index()`:

```
>>> grp_prof = grp_prof.reset_index()
>>> grp_prof
   TC_Code  Primary_CPT_Description  sum  mean  count_nonzero
0        0                        5   15    15              1
1        1                        6   16    16              1
2        2                        7   17    17              1
3        3                        8   18    18              1
4        4                        9   19    19              1
>>> grp_prof["Primary_CPT_Description"].idxmax()
4
```

---

To get the longest string, you need to get a Series of lengths first (new fake data):

```
>>> df["Primary_CPT_Description"]
0      A
1     BC
2    CDE
3      F
4     GH
Name: Primary_CPT_Description, dtype: object
>>> df["Primary_CPT_Description"].apply(len)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
Name: Primary_CPT_Description, dtype: int64
>>> df["Primary_CPT_Description"].apply(len).idxmax()
2
>>> df["Primary_CPT_Description"].str.len().idxmax()
2
```

Comment: @ DSM thanks. Your manufactured data is correct with one exception. The Description field is string with words in it (if that will make a difference, and I think it does given the error). I did the .reset_index(): and got the results you suggested. When I did the grp_prof["Primary_CPT_Description"].idxmax() I get a different error: "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @mylesg: ah, sorry.  I didn't notice (even though your post was clear) that you were trying to get the maximum length of a string with idxmax.  Will edit.